# Which weapon did a lot of actual damage from a single use?

Tags: weapon, brahmastra

The big name weapons like Brahmastra are often neutralized by the same or similar weapon.  When was the most damage inflicted by a single use of a weapon?

Comment: there are many but never used for big damage.. like Trishula (Trident) and Pashupatastra. I think Brahmastra caused most damage in a single use.

Comment: It depends what you define as "actual damage". The sundarsan chakra also eliminated powerful enemies.

Answer (score 1):

Indrajit employed Brahmastra by which Sixty seven crores of Vanaras were struck down in a single day.

> सप्तषष्टिर्हताः कोट्यो वानराणां तरस्विनाम् | अह्नः पञ्चमशेषेण वल्लभेन
>   स्वयम्भुवः || (Yuddha Kanda 74 Sarga 12 Sloka)
>
> Sixty seven crores of powerful monkeys were struck down by the
>   cherished missile of Brahma, the self-born creator, in the fifth and
>   last period of the day.